# STM32F103 при инициализации не запускается PLL и нестабильная работа кварцевого резонатора

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Есть микроконтроллер stm32f103c8t6 с кварцем на 10 МГц. Для программирования использую связку CubeMX (вер. 5.2.0) и библиотеку HAL (проверено на версиях 1.1.3 и 1.0.4). Во время инициализации при выполнении функции SystemClock_Config (код представлен ниже) микроконтроллер зависает при выполнении функции HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct).

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_OFF;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) // Вот здесь зависает
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO, RCC_MCO1SOURCE_HSE, RCC_MCODIV_1);
}
```

Если с помощью дебага зайти внутрь выполнения этой функции, то становится понятно, что МК зависает конкретно на этой строчке:

```
/* Enable the main PLL. */
__HAL_RCC_PLL_ENABLE();
```

Что, согласно описанию из самой библиотеки означает:

```
/** @brief Macro to enable the main PLL.
  * @note   After enabling the main PLL, the application software should wait on 
  *         PLLRDY flag to be set indicating that PLL clock is stable and can
  *         be used as system clock source.
  * @note   The main PLL is disabled by hardware when entering STOP and STANDBY modes.
  */
#define __HAL_RCC_PLL_ENABLE()          (*(__IO uint32_t *) RCC_CR_PLLON_BB = ENABLE)
```

То есть, когда запускается модуль PLL (на схеме тактирования выделено красным), он не выходит на стабильную частоту и мк вырубается.[image: Схема тактирования]
Если же в cubemx настроить тактирование ядра напрямую от кварца и в коде отключить PLL, то МК запускается, но проблемы на этом не заканчиваются.
Если запустить MCO (Master clock output) с тактированием от кварца и проверить с помощью логического анализатора частоту кварца, то можно увидеть что она нестабильна и далеко не равна 10 МГц. Она постоянно "прыгает" между 5.333 МГц и 8 МГц. Если запустить MCO с тактированием от внутреннего источника, то таких проблем нет. Данная проблема была обнаружена с двумя кварцами и на двух МК (хотя на одном мк проблемы с запуском PPL не было). [image: Скачки между 5.333 МГц и 8 МГц]
Следующий симптом моей проблемы. Если отключить PLL, настроить тактирование напрямую от кварца или внутреннего источника (который стабильно выдает свои 8 МГц) и "подёргать" пинами:

```
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

То видно, что измеренная задержка не соответствует той, которая написана в программе. Конкретно на данном примере, задержка получалась 2 мс, вместо 1 мс, вне зависимости от источника тактирования. До возникновения описанной проблемы я уже неоднократно работал с данным МК и данными библиотеками, и, конечно же, никакой схожей проблемы не возникало. Разница данного проекта от предыдущих лишь в следующем: если раньше я работал с китайскими платами с таким МК на борту, на которых стоит кварц 8 МГц, то сейчас создается отдельное устройство с этим МК и кварцом на 10 МГц. Ещё обращу внимание, что в помещении, где производится сборка, много статики, что может послужить не самым лучшим образом. Хотя мне кажется, что статика должна ломать МК полностью, а не только лишь какие то отдельные модули.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Решил спаять третий модуль и посмотреть что будет. Модуль PLL заработал сразу. Поставил тактирование через него. Код в бесконечном цикле тот же самый, но вместо задержки 1 мс поставил задержку 13 мс:

```
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_3);
        HAL_Delay(13);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

Получаемая по факту задержка равна стабильные 14 мс, что, как и в прошлые разы, на 1 мс больше чем надо. Общеизвестно, что HAL не самая быстрая библиотека, но задержка на 1 мс при простом переключении ног невозможна. Также никуда не делся вопрос к работе кварца. Только теперь "скачки" между 8 МГц и 12 МГц.[image: Скачки между 8 МГц и 12 МГц]

Comment: Кварцевый резонатр не может нестабильно работать по определению. А вот чип может не успевать справляться с программой на такой частоте, и пропускать один из циклов тактирования.

Comment: `сейчас создаётся отдельное устройство`. Если раньше этот код работал нормально, то возможно проблема в электрической схеме. Было бы неплохо на неё посмотреть.

Comment: На самом деле бывает, что сгорает какой-то отдельный модуль контроллера, а не контроллер целиком. Причем довольно часто.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря с комментариям выше и экспериментам с моими модулями и китайскими платами с тем же микроконтроллером, удалось прояснить хоть и не все, но многие вопросы.

Проблемы с модулем PLL связаны с его выходом оного из строя. На пяти проверенных МК с одинаковыми программами, проблема с PLL возникла лишь на одном. Причина этого не выяснена, вполне возможно, что из-за статики.

Кварц работает стабильно, несмотря на измерения логическим анализатором. Проверял следующим образом: отправлял множество сообщений по UART со скоростью 500000 б/с. Никаких ошибок, связанных с синхронизацией, в передаче не было.

Что за задержка 1 мс при "дёргании" пинами выяснено не было.

Также было выяснено, что, при тактировании ядра МК напрямую с кварца, могут возникать проблемы с интерфейсами связи. Конкретно в моём проекте это было проверено на CAN Bus. Причём он не работал самым коварным образом: никаких ошибок при сборке проекте, никаких ошибок при компиляции программы, никаких ошибок во время работы и дебага, но сообщения всё равно не принимались и не отправлялись. Но стоило поменять источник тактирования на исправном МК обратно на PLL и поменять настройки CAN'а, чтобы получить ту же скорость передачи, то всё сразу заработало как надо.